# Minimize vs Minimalize

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, is-it-a-word

First, is *minimalize* a word?

If so, what is the difference between the two words *minimalize* and *minimize,* and when should each be used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several dictionaries do not have an entry for *minimalize* (such as [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/minimalize) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimalize)).  Still, other dictionaries do (such as [Random House, via Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/minimalize) and [Webster's New World and American Heritage, via YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/minimalize)), and the word is definitely in use, so the answer to the first part of your question is yes, it's a word.

The difference between *minimize* and *minimalize* is very subtle.  In many cases, either word would work and they would mean the same thing.  However, some would argue that *minimalize* implies striving for [*minimalism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism), which isn't quite the same as simply making as small as possible.  One blogger who describes himself as a minimalist specifically uses both words in the title of an article, in an effort to highlight the difference: ["The Goal is to Minimalize Consumption, not to Minimize It"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150124000946/www.alanfurth.com/consumption).

[Some claim](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst19675_new-word.aspx) that *minimalize* means something akin to "portray as small or unimportant"; whereas *minimize* means to actually make something small.  This distinction doesn't jibe with the definitions for *minimize* given in various dictionaries covering both of those uses.  For example, from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/minimize):

> Reduce (something, especially something unwanted or unpleasant) to the smallest possible amount or degree: *the aim is to minimize costs*
> Represent or estimate at less than the true value or importance: *they may minimize, or even overlook, the importance of such beliefs*

I believe that this misconception comes from conflating *minimalize* with *marginalize*:

[Again, from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/marginalize)]:

> Treat (a person, group, or concept) as insignificant or peripheral: *attempting to marginalize those who disagree*

Comment: I agree with this premise and summary and am surprised this is still the top search result for the word 10 years later.  I would like to add that I believe the conflation is with *minimize* and *marginalize* — but *minimalize*, at least in common usage with those around me — is used as a directional form of marginalize.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed. They don't mean exactly the same:

According to Macmillan:

**minimize**:

1. to reduce something harmful or unpleasant to the smallest amount or degree: *We must minimize the damage to innocent civilians.*
2. to make something seem much less important than it really is: "I don't want to minimize their role in the campaign.

"minimalize" would suggest "to reduce something *as much as possible*, as minimalists tend to do"

Answer (score 1):

They both mean the same. Since there are 5,279 records for *minimize* in the Corpus of Contemporary American English and only 4 for *minimalize*, there seems no real reason for using the longer version.

Answer (score 0):

They do not mean the same thing. Minimize means to make smaller, to reduce.  Minimalize means to make less of something.

Comment: I've heard of the argument: mini means small, minimal means smallest, so minimalize is even smaller, but I'm not sure because I can't find references on web. Are there references supporting your answer?

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, it seems that the difference is in the "attempt to" (minimalize) vs. "implementation of" (minimize); however, both share the same idea so usage is completely circumstantial.